# False Javascript errors in Eclispe

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

Somewhat regrettably, I've gotten used to using Eclipse while it seems the rest of the world has moved over to Visual Code. The latter isn't necessarily worse to me, it is however different enough to make me non-productive. Unfortunately, it doesn't like modern Javascript and for the code below (and similar throughout) I get errors like:

```
  describe('.info', function() {
    var package = require('../package.json'),
      info = sass.info;

    it('should return a correct version info', function(done) {
      assert(info.indexOf(package.version) > 0);
      assert(info.indexOf('(Wrapper)') > 0);
      assert(info.indexOf('[JavaScript]') > 0);
      assert(info.indexOf('[NA]') < 0);
      assert(info.indexOf('(Sass Compiler)') > 0);
      assert(info.indexOf('[C/C++]') > 0);

      done();
    });
  });
});
```

',' expected
Semicolon expected
'}' expected
')' expected

Before it is asked, I do have Javascript validation turned on, but it would be nice if I could keep it on, only with a working version of Javascript validation and not a syntax checker from 1995.

My Eclipse version is the Java EE IDE distribution:

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200
```

Sample of one error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
',' expected    api.js  /my-project-rules-client/client/node_modules/node-sass/test line 2024   JavaScript Problem
```

Comment: Can you show the full error? Eclipse should come with a valid syntax checker for at the very least es5 syntax.

Comment: And I would assume you'd want to know what lines those errors are marking.